# Why I am receiving this sql error?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-insert, sqlexception

I started my java code in NetBeans, I wanted to insert some data in my `numbersdb` table located in the database `firstdb`. I'm having problems when I run the program.

My code is this one:

```
public static void main(String [] arg){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded!");
        Connection dbc = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/firstdb", "root","root");
        System.out.println("Connection to database succeded!");

        boolean evening = false;
        int n100 = 1;
        int n10 = 2;
        int n1 = 3;
        int wn = 123;
        int month = 0;
        int day = 0;
        int year = 0;
        java.sql.Date date_released = new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());

        String query =  "insert into numbersdb (hundreds_place, tens_place, ones_place, whole_number, evening, date_released, day, month, year) "+
                        " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbc.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, n100);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, n10);
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, n1);
        preparedStatement.setInt(4, wn);
        preparedStatement.setBoolean(5, evening);
        preparedStatement.setDate(6, date_released);
        preparedStatement.setInt(7, day);
        preparedStatement.setInt(8, month);
        preparedStatement.setInt(9, year);

        preparedStatement.execute(query);       

        System.out.println("Query executed!!!");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
    } 
}
```

I created my database with this sql code in phpmyadmin:

```
create table numbersdb (  
    hundreds_place int unsigned not null,  
    tens_place int unsigned not null,   
    ones_place int unsigned not null,   
    whole_number int unsigned not null,  
    evening boolean not null,  
    date_released date not null,  
    day int unsigned not null,  
    month int unsigned not null,  
    year int unsigned not null,  
    primary key (date_released)  
);
```

The output of my program is this one:

> Driver loaded!   Connection to database succeded!   SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1   SQLState: 42000
>   VendorError: 1064

Why am I getting this exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preparedStatement.execute(query);
```

This line uses `.execute(String)` inherited from `Statement`. Said method only executes the given query that now contains the `?`'s.

Remove the argument to use the correct method and it'll work.

```
preparedStatement.execute();
```

Comment: +1.  But `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()` might be more appropriate.